# Streaming Torrent Files in HTML Browser

Tags: html, video, streaming, torrent

I am looking for a way to play video torrent files before they have finished downloading, and I would like to to play it in my web browser. I know there are certain torrent clients which are able to do this, but I do not understand how. Aren't the parts of the video file downloaded in random, disconnected chunks? I mean, I would like to just repeatedly play the .part video files in my web browser, but I don't see how this is possible if the parts are disconnected until the video file is completely finished downloading. Could someone point me in the right direction of some sources if I would like to understand the process of streaming video torrent files in my web browser? I would be less interested in already created tools which achieve this and more interested in the underlying concepts.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to do it in your browser then you need to be looking at either magic player http://magicplayer.torrentstream.net which is a plugin for all the best broswers (yes IE is not in that list) or you can take a look at web torrrent if you want to host the site yourself, it uses pure JS to stream your video file https://github.com/feross/webtorrent